# Check if app is iPhone app opened on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, swift

I have developed keyboard for iOS 8. Depending on if device is iPhone or iPad i load different layouts. Now, i have an issue when user opening app (for example: Instagram) which is iPhone app but downloaded on iPad and of course iPad resizes this app. My keyboard detects device as an iPad and loads layout for iPad but as the app is not and iPad app, loaded keyboard layout is not suitable for it. Shortly, Is there any way to check programmatically if app is iPhone app resized by iPad? So i can load proper keyboard layout for it.

Comment: Your question title and description does not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is about any generic app, **the answer is no**.
Your keyboard app cannot find out whether the installed app is iphone based or iPad.

If the developer of both the apps are same, you can have some specific value which can be shared through clientUrl.

Comment: That is sad. May be possible to detect it using screen width or resolution? When iPad resizes iPhone app there might be a difference on width and height i hope.

Comment: You should consider that even if that exists you keyboard app will not get the notification about it. :(  https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW3

Answer (score 2):

If the app is an iPhone app (like Instagram in your example) running in the emulator mode on an iPad, it will have a userInterfaceIdiom of Phone, but a model type of iPad. You can check this with the following code:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone &&
    [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] hasPrefix:@"iPad"]) {
    // This app is an iPhone app running on an iPad, use iPhone-style layout
}
```

Hopefully this works for your custom keyboard.

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer seems to work. Tested by running an iPhone only app on an iPad Air2 with iOS9.3. The result from UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM is always UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this exact same issue and the only solution I have come up with is to compare the my keyboard's width with the device's screen width.

As all custom iOS keyboards fill the width of their host app, then that means if the keyboard width is less than the width of the device's screen, then it must be running with some padding around the edge. i.e. the keyboard is being presented in an iPhone app which is being displayed on an iPad

```
let keyboardWidth = self.keyboardView.frame.size.width
let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width

if (keyboardWidth < screenWidth) 
{
    print("The keyboard is being displayed in an iPhone app that is running on an iPad.")
}
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

if you call:

```
if(IS_IPHONE) {
    //Device is a iPhone
}
else {
    //Device is a iPAD
}
```

Comment: I am using same way. But this just detects if device is iPhone or iPad. i need a special case, to detect if app is iPhone app opened on iPad.

Comment: You did not understand the question.